# Self-referencing recurrence relation with exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences, exponential-sums, exponential-polynomials

I have the self-referencing recurrence relation
$$
d(0) = 0
$$
$$
d(1) = a
$$
$$
d(n+1) = d(n) + a*e^{-(\frac{d(n)-n*c}{b})^4} 
$$
Written as a sum:
$$
d(N) = a*\sum_{n=0}^{N}e^{-(\frac{d(n)-n*c}{b})^4} 
$$
d(N) is a measured variable of a physical system. The constants b and c are given. What I want to do: Measure d(N), then determine the constant a from that. To do so, I need a closed form equation for the recurrence relation. The special case of $c = 0$ would already bring me further.

Here is a graphic to illustrate what I am trying to do: Exemplary plots of d(N) for four different values of a (c = 0, b = 300) and three points representing measured values of d for three different N. I would like to find a from the measurements (in this example, a is approximately 1.5).
[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could show me a way to solve the problem, or point me to an existing solution.

Comment: a closed-form solution is unlikely, why not work with a numerical solution? the sequence $d(n)$ converges rapidly for large $n$.

Comment: A numerical solution, gladly!

But that's where my limited math skills get me nowhere. For a numerical solution, wouldn’t I still need to re-formulate
$$
d(N) = f(N, a, b, c) = a*\sum_{n=0}^{N}e^{-(\frac{d(n)-n*c}{b})^4} 
$$
somehow to get
$$a = f(d(N, b, c))$$ ?

Comment: Why don’t you show me some of your data, and I will see if I can extract this coefficient a from it.

Comment: I think it will help to know the actual values of $b$ and $c$, or at least their signs/ranges. Also, is $a$ positive? Also, what are ranges of values for $N$ and $d(N)$?

Comment: Also, are you sure that $d(1)=a$ rather than $ae^{-(c/b)^4}$ as both the recursion and your summation formula (in which $N$ should probably be $N-1$) suggest?

Comment: Well, there are no data like a list of d(n) values for each experiment. One experiment consists of applying N iterations and then measuring d(N). The experiment may be repeated multiple times with different values of N. The values of $a$ thus determined are distributed around the expectation value of $a$, but the nature of this distribution is unknown. $a, b, c, d(N)$ are positive real numbers. Typical values are $a\in[0.1, 10.0], b\in[50.0, 200.0], c\in[0,10.0], d(N)\in[50,1000]$. The integer N is $\in[100, 5000]$.

Comment: It seems to me your graph already essentially gives the numerical solution. Just try out different values of $a$ until you find agreement with the measured value. Of course, do the search efficiently - say, you know that $a\in [a_-,a_+]$, then bisect the interval - try $a=(a_- + a_+)/2$ to establish a new interval half as large. This converges rapidly. I would do this for each measured value separately and analyze the obtained distribution of $a$ afterwards.